# Summer 17 LockerService Error while using Node.contains

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service, summer-17

When I try to execute the following code:

`this.root.contains(this.element)` where root is a `"SecureElement: [object HTMLDivElement]{ key: {"namespace":"xyz"} }"` and element is a `"SecureElement: [object HTMLDivElement]{ key: {"namespace":"xyz"} }"`, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at Proxy.value
```

The error comes from `SecureObject.$createFilteredMethodStateless$` on the `var fnReturnedValue = raw[methodName].apply(raw, filteredArgs);` line. In the `filteredArgs`, LockerService passes a `Proxy` object instead of the actual HTMLDivElement element. When I check `filteredArgs[0] instanceof Node` it really returns `true`.

This probably happens because the `contains` method uses native code. Here's the Mozilla documentation about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Who can fix this?

**Edit:** it seems like all the `Node` native methods have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed repro steps and investigation. I've verified this is, in fact, a real issue and am working on a fix now. I'll update with an answer as progress is made.

Comment: Any news @TrevorBliss? This is blocking my LockerService release.

Comment: On track for the .3 patch. I only fixed this for 4 of the native `Node` APIs though. If you see the issue anywhere besides `contains`, `compareDocumentPosition`, `isEqualNode`, or `isSameNode`, please let us know.

Comment: @TrevorBliss I still have problems with Node.appendChild (by using jQuery `appendTo()` method). Still, it calls some native code, still on the `Node` object and still we have a proxy instead of a Node instance, and still `instanceOf Node` returns `true`.

Comment: @TrevorBliss do you have any news?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't heard anything new with that API. I actually moved away from LockerService so you may want to open up a customer case or pursue other channels to get that looked at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific issue for `Node.contains()` and a few other Node APIs are currently scheduled to be fixed in the .3 patch. Of course, this can be delayed if any issues are found with the fix but things are looking on track so far.

Thanks again for detailed bug report and initial debugging.

Comment: Any word on fixes to `Range.setStart()`?