# LockerService Error while using Range.setStart

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

Why does LockerService Error while using Range.setStart?

Getting the error "Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

This is when using popper.js dependency in a LockerService component. This seems to be because Locker Service is passing a Proxy Object rather than the DOM element it is expecting.

Here is the API docs for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart, would expect this fails for setEnd as well.

Looks very similar to the previously reported & fixed issue: [Summer 17 LockerService Error while using Node.contains](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170700/summer-17-lockerservice-error-while-using-node-contains)

Relevant code is in https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/blob/master/packages/popper/src/utils/findCommonOffsetParent.js (lines 27-29)

```
  // Get common ancestor container
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(start, 0);
  range.setEnd(end, 0);
  const { commonAncestorContainer } = range;
```

This library is used in React - Lightning Design System (https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com) the official react library that implements the lightning Design System so I believe it is pretty essential this is supported.

Comment: Could you please **[edit]** your post to actually ask a question? Additionally, could you add any relevant code? Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianLarson done.

Comment: Please include your code on *this* site. A good question or answer here does not require a user to navigate elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianLarson added the broken code directly

Comment: Try to change your API version to 39

Comment: Nearly two years have passed. Is there any chance this will be addressed? The alternative for us to rip out entire pieces of our infrastructure which depend on the `Range` object and rewrite them.

Comment: When you go to fix this I'm sure you'll quickly realize that the same problem applies to other APIs as well, such as `setStartBefore`.